# Pre-emptive scheduling algorithm

Tags: operating-system

Can a first come first serve algorithm with priority levels be described as a pre-emptive scheduling algorithm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traditionally *first come first serve algorithm* was used in Batch scheduling.

In most cases there is no existence of a pure form of "preemptive scheduling" , but preemptive scheduling is mixed with other policies like round robin , shortest job first etc . So yes there may be implementations where *first come first serve algorithm* is used along with preemptive scheduling.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely NO. The original First Come First Served is a non-preemptive scheduling strategy. I don't know whether there is any alternative/revision of this algorithm that can be implemented as preemptive FCFS. You can find this in the "Operating System Concept" by Abraham Silberschatz et al.

Answer (score 0):

FCFS doesn't consider priorities. If you need to consider priorities, then you have to go with Priority Scheduling; which is an extended version of FCFS. Then it becomes a preemptive scheduling method.